# How do I remove comment lines from an Oracle CSV export?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I am exporting data from an Oracle database to csv file using the spool command as follows:

```
set heading off
set linesize 1000
set long 1000
set pagesize 0
set echo off
set verify off

spool D:\OVERNIGHT\TEMP_FILES\SE_NEW_PFRA_CRYSTAL_OUTPUT.txt


SELECT
TRIM(FU_BAN) ||'|'||
TRIM(CASE_ID) ||'|'||
TRIM(case when fu_type is null then 'unknown' else fu_type end)  ||'|'||
TO_CHAR(FU_OPEN_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')  ||'|'||
TO_CHAR(FU_DUE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')  ||'|'||
TO_CHAR(FU_LATEST_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') ||'|'||
TRIM(X_CASE2X_BUS_ORG)  ||'|'||
TRIM(TOPIC1)  ||'|'||
TRIM(TOPIC2) ||'|'||
TRIM(TOPIC3)||'|'||
TRIM(FU_OPENED_BY1) ||'|'||
TRIM(FU_ASSIGNED1_TO) ||'|'||
TRIM(CASE_STATE2CONDITION) ||'|'||
TRIM(FU_STATUS) ||'|'||
TRIM(FU_OPENED_BY) ||'|'||
TRIM(FU_ASSIGNED_TO) 
FROM  SE_PFRA_REPORT_WRK T1;

SPOOL OFF

EXIT;
```

The data is exported but at the bottom there is a linesace then a line stating xxxx rows selected.

How can I set the script so it doesn't export these lines?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Steve

Comment: It's time to accept an answer, Steve.

Answer (score 8):

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
```

is the command you are looking for.

Full example here... http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/flatfile.html

Answer (score 3):

Just found the answer.

For thos who don't know I added the line

```
set feedback off
```

and this cleared the offending lines.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the (already mentioned and correct) `set feedback off` you might also want to `set trimspool on`.

This will cuts lines after the last space. Without it, every line spooled would end up with 1000 characters width (as set in `set linesize`).